# How to export an input in Pajek Format or save sentences followed by objects

Tags: r, dataframe, save, sentence

I would like to know how can I save some text lines followed by a dataframe.
Actually I want to export an input for pajek to analyze in other program, and everything that I have seen about inputs for pajek is for using within R.
So finally I have decided to prepare manually the input, but I need save all together.

For example,

Imagine that I have the network

```
1 a
1 c
2 c
2 d
3 d
```

And I want to prepare an Input for an anlaysis where I consider a bipartite network an unweighted.

Here I put what I have performed to prepare the input manually.

```
# First data frame
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
first_df <- rbind (cbind (a,a),cbind(b,b))
number <- seq (1, nrow (first_df), 1)
vertices <- cbind (number, first_df [,1]) 

#Second dataframe
c <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
d <- c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
links <- cbind (c,d)

#First sentence
cat ("*Vertices", nrow(vertices))    

#Second sentece 
cat ("*Edges", nrow (links))
```

I would like to save the first sentence, the first data frame (vertices), the second sentence and the second data frame (links). It hasn't to save the `row.names` or `col.names`.
The final result that I want is:

```
*Vertices 8    
1 "1"
2 "2"
3 "3"
4 "4"
5 "a"
6 "b"
7 "c"
8 "d"
*Edges 5
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

I would appreciate if you can help me with this or if you can explain how I can export directly the input from the network:

```
1 a
1 c
2 c
2 d
3 d
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you built an actual graph structure with `igraph` it easily saves it out to pajek format via `write.graph`

Comment: What is what you consider the graph from the code that I have written? I have tried with the original data frame that indicate the relationships (1 a / 1 c / 2 c / 2 d / 3 d), and the dataframes but they are not consider as graphs. Could you tell me how I can get the graph from the original dataframe? Thanks in advance

Comment: (a) you are outputting to pajek so it's a graph (b) you claimed to have done research on exporting to pajek in R and found nothing (c) turn your data frame into an `igraph` object and use `write.graph` vs reinvent the wheel.